# Ext JS grid get dom of last selected row

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, sencha-architect

Is there any chance to get the `DOM` values of the last selected row inside a grid. I could only get the record with values and not the `DOM` elements. With `DOM` elements I mean the `<tr>` element of the row selected.

```
var selectedRecord = grid.getSelectionModel().getLastSelected();
```

//only gets the model instance that is selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use grid's view [`getNode()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.View-method-getNode) method. It returns HTMLElement of the grid record's row. If you want to do something with row HTML element you can use [`Ext.get()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-get) method to obtain `Ext.dom.Element` object.

```
// selected record
var selectedRecord = grid.getSelectionModel().getLastSelected();

// row HTMLElement
var node = grid.view.getNode(selectedRecord);

// Ext.dom.Element object
var el = Ext.get(node);
```