# How to get DOM node in Ext.view.View by Record?

Tags: dom, extjs, dataview

I am using ExtJS 4.2.3 to create a small JavaScript application. In that application i have a Ext.view.View with a custom template to show the data.

On select/deselect i would like to animate a part of the item. At the moment i am using the select/deselect events of the Ext.view.View to trigger the animation. The problem is that this events only get a reference to the record that was selected/deselected. How can i get the matching DOM node within the Ext.view.View in order to trigger the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ext.view.View.getNode method to get the selected HTML Element, from selected Record object

[Ext.view.View](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.view.View)

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403955/ext-js-grid-get-dom-of-last-selected-row